# I am trying to get token but not able to extract it using JSON extractor

Tags: json, jmeter, jwt

1. This is my JSON extractor

[image]

2. Debug sampler

[image]

3. Token I am getting in response

[image]

4. But the token is null

Answer (score 0):

Your setup is wrong, the [JSON attribute](http://niem.github.io/reference/concepts/property/attribute/json/) you're looking for is `token`, not the `access_token` therefore you need to amend your [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression to look like:

```
$.token
```

also it's hard to say looking at the image on which level the `token` lives, you might need to use [deep scan operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) instead like:

```
$..token
```

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)